# geopandas is drawing a map upside down

Tags: geopandas

The following code snippet draws a map of US counties, but it is upside down.

```py
import geopandas as gpd

gpd.read_file("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/us-atlas@3/counties-albers-10m.json").plot()
```

I tried setting different CRS values without any success.

This looks like an issue with the TopoJSON file, but I could not find any alternatives with the same compact layout. Please let me know if you find one.

[image: US counties upside down]

Comment: I don't know what is the cause of the issue but if it's just for plotting you could try to invert the Y-coordinates.

Comment: I could not go further than finding the GitHub project to which this asset seems linked: https://github.com/topojson/us-atlas?tab=readme-ov-file, which at least indicates the projection of the map.

Comment: Another piece of information concerning the projection, which is a composite one: https://d3js.org/d3-geo/conic#geoAlbersUsa